# Remake a JQuery function to allow it to be called any time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know it's a stupid question but I'm quite new to JQuery and I have a preatty basic problem...
This function is called on `mousemove`
How can I remake it so I can call it any time?

```js
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e){
 $('#cursor').css({
  left: e.pageX - 7,
  top: e.pageY - 7
 });
});
```

Comment: It seems like you're using the event properties `pageX` and `pageY` inside the function, how do you expect to get those values when you call the function at any time?

Comment: Well... I'm drawing a div after mouse position and I am in situation where i need to call it instantly as a function. Thats the problem.

Comment: That is the problem - you can't get those variables from the event object because IIRC event objects can only be called inside event handlers, not inside functions, unless you attach that function to an event handler.

Comment: At the point that you want to call it yourself, do you have the `pageX` and `pageY` you would want the `e` object to have when calling it?

Comment: Is there a way to do it? Well... I only need to somehow detect mouse position on the go... And then apply those values to div's position...

Comment: Let me explain it in other way around... This function is nested in another function... I need it to work instantly after the parent one is executed

Comment: Okay, and how is this parent function gets invoked?

Comment: It is:      list = {  execute : function() { Some code and the nested function }  }   and then list.execute();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to use the pointer coordinates inside a nested function, may be you can keep track of them in some variables.

```
var posX, posY;

$(document).on('mousemove', function(e){
    $('#cursor').css({
        left:   e.pageX - 7,
        top:    e.pageY - 7
    });
    posX = e.pageX;
    posY = e.pageY;

});

function parentFunction(){
   //Some code

   $('#cursor').css({
        left:   posX - 7,
        top:    posY - 7
    });
}

parentFunction();
```

Comment: I know that Comments are not to say "thank you".... But i'll break this rule and say thank you... After slightly editing your example i finally got it to work!

Answer (score 0):

You might do it like this (please see comments in the code):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // setup an object to store mouse position
  var mousepos = {};
  // update the object on mousemove
  $(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    mousepos = {
      x: e.pageX,
      y: e.pageY
    }
  });

  // setup a function to update cursor position
  function setCursor() {
    $('#cursor').css({
      left: mousepos.x - 7,
      top: mousepos.y - 7
    });
  }

  // your code
  list = {
    execute: function() {
      // Some code and the nested function 
      setCursor();
    }
  };

  list.execute();

});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I figured it out with help from someone else. The problem was that "div" cursor got it's position reset after executing several timing functions which were handling animations between changing pages. I fell like your example is better. But Ome more question... Why can't an event be called like a normal function?

Comment: @FalsePride, there are 3 different things you're messing up: [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event), [`eventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener) and [`handleEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener/handleEvent). Where only `handleEvent` is a function.